# How to send fs.stat details in JSON format to front end AngularJS as a response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, stat

I want output that gets the listing of path and gets each file name with the associated file size. I get this output in the command prompt, but I want
node to store this record and send response to the *controller.js* file.

#### My folder structure is:

> node_modules
>   public
>   ->controllers
>                  - controller.js
>   ->index.html
>    server.js

#### Code of server.js i.e backend code Node.js:

```
    var express = require('express');     
    var app = express();      
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');     
    var http = require('http');     
    var fs = require('fs');      
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));        
    app.use(bodyParser.json());       
    var dir ='';       
    var result = [];         
    app.post('/filelist', function (req,res){           
        console.log(req.body);         
        dir = req.body.name;        
        res.end();          
    });     

    app.get('/filelist', function (req, res) {            
          console.log("I received a GET request")                
          fs.exists(dir, (exists) => {         
                if (exists) {        
                    console.log("file exist " + dir);       
                    fs.readdir(dir,function(err, items){         
                      if (err) {         
                          return console.error(err);       
                      }        
                      for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {       
                          var file = dir + '/' + items[i];     
                          console.log(file);     
                          fs.stat(file, generate_callback(file));          
                      }      
                    });       
                }     
                else {       
                console.error('myfile does not exist');         
                res.json({message: 'Requested "'+dir+'" file or folder does not exist!'               
                });          
                }     
          });      
          function generate_callback(file) {          
              return function(err, stats) {           
                  result = ({name:file.substring(6),Size:stats["size"]});           
                  console.log(result);         
                  res.json(result);         
              }     
          };      
    });      
    app.listen(3000);        
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

**controller.js**

```
  function AppCtrl($scope, $http){       
      console.log("Hello world from controller");         
      var refresh = function() {           
          $http.get('/filelist').success(function(response){        
              console.log("I got the data I requested");        
              $scope.filelist = response;        
              $scope.list = "";        
              $scope.msg = response.message;           
          });        
      };     
      $scope.searchPath = function() {         
          console.log($scope.contact);        
          $http.post('/filelist', $scope.list).success(function(response){           
              console.log(response);        
              refresh();        
          });      
      };     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the NodeJS code, don't call `res.json()` until processing each file. One way to do this is to pass the number of files in the directory to the callback function -

```
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {       
    var file = dir + '/' + items[i];     
    console.log(file);     
    // pass the number of items in the directory to the callback here
    fs.stat(file, generate_callback(file,items.length));
}
```

Then in the callback, add the results of each file to an array (e.g. `var results`) and when the *length* property of that array is equal to the number of items in the directory, call `res.json()`:

```
var results = [];
function generate_callback(file,numberOfItems) {
    return function(err, stats) {           
        result = ({name:file.substring(0,6),Size:stats["size"]});
        results.push(result);//add the result for the current file to the list of results
        //when we have reached the last file, send the results in JSON format
        if (results.length == numberOfItems){
            res.json(results);
        }
    }     
};
```

I have this running on [codeenv.com](http://codeenv.com) - see the angular page utilizing the nodeJS *filelist* endpoint [here](https://ndustx1.codeenv.com/5cb375b6753e/web/index) - if that stops working, you should be able to open [the environment](https://codeenv.com/env/run/gKKyag/), click the *Launch* button in the upper right corner of the screen, and then in the terminal run `node server.js` to start the server.